# Passing data between fragments (tried all solutions

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-navigation

I've read (or tryied) all about here but I'm unable to pass a simple integer value between two fragments.

My code is simple

Fragment 1

```
Bundle n = new Bundle();
n.putInt("Id", 1); // test value
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
navController.navigate(R.id.serviceDetailFragment, n);
```

Fragment 2

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle b = getArguments();
if (b != null) {
        `enter code here`serviceId = b.getInt("Id");
    }
```

}

but b is already NULL (in fragment 1 it is correctly intantiated and value set to a in int i.e. 1 or 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the global variable and then use it.
Like this

**Mainactivity.java**

```
static public int a;
```

**Fragment1**

```
Mainactivity.a=1
```

**Fragment2**

```
Somevar=Mainactivity.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment 1 (Sending data):

```
Bundle n = new Bundle();
n.putInt("Id", 1); // test value
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
navController.navigate(R.id.serviceDetailFragment, n);
```

remove the onCreate method from Fragment 2, and replace it with the following onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_service_detail, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        int serviceId = getArguments().getInt("Id");
        // Now you can use the serviceId value as needed
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if (b != null) {
            serviceId = b.getInt("Id");
        }


Done (i've used OnCreate 'cause I want that methoud would be called once  and not every time)... but results are the same... always null :(